# Routing packets from one host to other on Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, routing

I have a `server` and a `pc`. Both installed Ubuntu. `server` has docker installed, and I want to route my packets from `pc` to that `server`. Both ifconfig outputs: (relevant parts only)

**server:**

```
docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  
          inet addr:172.17.42.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet    
          inet addr:192.168.1.2  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

**pc:**

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet 
          inet addr:192.168.1.4  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

I want to add a routing rule to `pc`, so that anything that matches `172.17.0.0/255.255.0.0` are routed to `server0`. (Because docker containers have IPs like that) How should I do that? I am confused with route add method, it is like

```
route add -net $NET netmask $MASK gw $GATEWAY
```

I think `$NET` should be `172.17.0.0` and `$MASK` should be `255.255.0.0` but what should the `$GATEWAY` be? Am I using the wrong tool? Because on pc it gives:

```
# route 
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out gateway should be `server` address of course, it works brilliantly.